# Algorithm to determine whether a power of a prime ideal is primary in a polynomial ring over a field

Tags: commutative-algebra, algorithms

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of a polynomial ring $k[X_1,\cdots, X_m]$ over a field $k$.
Suppose a finite basis of $P$ is given.
Is there an algorithm to determine whether $P^n$ is primary for a given positive integer $n$?
If yes, what is it?

Comment: Regarding the close votes: This question lacks information on where you encountered the problem (or what issues caused you to come up with it) and also lacks information on what you have already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @CarlMummert Since I don't want to pollute this thread with a meta issue, I have opened [a meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13185/why-was-this-question-asking-an-algorithm-to-determine-whether-a-power-of-a-prim). Let us discuss there.

Comment: For the benefit of those members who are not fully conversant with the definitions let me add a link to a relevant [wiki-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_ideal). I know next to nothing about commutative algebra, but it does sound like it would help to think, whether a proof of Lasker-Noether theorem gives an algorithm for finding a minimal primary decomposition of a given ideal. Adding such stuff would make it easier for readers. Also, is there a geometric motivation for this question?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen It is well-known that $P^n$ is not necessarily primary.
I think it is natural to ask whether $P^n$ is primary for a given prime ideal $P$ and an integer $n$.

Comment: But does Lasker-Noether give an algorithm for determining whether a given ideal is primary or not? I'm not conversant with what is known about various minimal primary decompositions, so I cannot tell. Can you shed more light to that?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen [*But does Lasker-Noether give an algorithm for determining whether a given ideal is primary or not?*]
What do you mean by Lasker-Noether?
Do you mean by it the famous thorem on primary decompositions?
If so, the theorem does not give an algorithm.

Comment: @MakotoKato I do not know whether your specific question is addressed there, but there is a nice book that I've consulted in the past on algorithmic issues of a similar flavor. It may be worth taking a look, if easily accessible: Teo Mora, **Solving polynomial equation systems**, 2 volumes, Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications, CUP, 2003 & 2005.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I will check it when I have a chance to see it. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.6/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_primary_spdecomposition.html). Isn't it so that an ideal is primary, iff its list of associated primes is a singleton? So if there are algorithms for producing the associated primes, then you can use that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. It seems that the algorithm requires the ground field to be a prime field.
Anyway, I would like to know the algorithm.

Comment: Here are meta threads which are related to this thread.
They were closed and deleted for reasons I don't understand.
Users who have high reps can see them.

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13185/why-was-this-question-asking-an-algorithm-to-determine-whether-a-power-of-a-prim

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13208/whats-wrong-with-posting-a-meta-question-asking-for-the-reason-for-the-closure

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13210/public-question-to-moderator-alex-becker